# filter tibble of tibbles by nrow

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I've a tibble like that

```
>dat
# A tibble: 556 × 3
           sample      run                   abc
            <chr>    <chr>                <list>
1  206_03_07_2013 21102016   <tibble [304 × 21]>
2  206_04_07_2017  7082017   <tibble [229 × 21]>
3  206_04_10_2015 25112015 <tibble [2,687 × 21]>
4  206_07_08_2013 15102015   <tibble [460 × 21]>
5  206_08_12_2016  3032017 <tibble [3,250 × 21]>
6  206_11_03_2014 21102016   <tibble [975 × 21]>
7  206_13_02_2013 21112016   <tibble [101 × 21]>
8  206_13_03_2013 21112016   <tibble [345 × 21]>
9  206_14_08_2014  8092016 <tibble [1,952 × 21]>
10 206_19_03_2015 25012016    <tibble [11 × 21]>
# ... with 546 more rows
```

The abc column contains tibble of different length. I want to filter the dat tibble using their length (>100 rows).

I could do something like that :

```
dat[sapply(dat$abs,nrow)>100,]
```

but I would like to use dplyr phylosophy ?
Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example using `dput`

Answer (score 1):

A way could be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat <- tribble(
  ~foo, ~bar,
  1, as_tibble(head(iris, 3)),
  2, as_tibble(head(iris, 7))
)

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#     foo              bar
#   <dbl>           <list>
# 1     1 <tibble [3 x 5]>
# 2     2 <tibble [7 x 5]>

res <- filter(dat, map_int(bar, nrow) > 5)

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#     foo              bar
#   <dbl>           <list>
# 1     2 <tibble [7 x 5]>

desired_output <- dat[sapply(dat$bar,nrow)>5,]
identical(res, desired_output)
# [1] TRUE
```

There is not really any added value here, compared to what you tried, it's a matter of using drop-in replacements to `[` and `sapply` (with `filter` and `map_int` respectively). Base R functions are not incompatible with the so-called "`dplyr` philosophy". If you mean the use of the `magrittr` pipe `%>%`, `dat %>% .[sapply(.$bar, nrow) > 5, ]` and `dat %>% filter(map_int(bar, nrow) > 5)` work equally well.

Note: I usually prefer `all.equal` over `identical` but couldn't make it work:

```
all.equal(res, desired_output)
# Error in equal_data_frame(target, current, ignore_col_order = ignore_col_order,  : 
#   Can't join on 'bar' x 'bar' because of incompatible types (list / list)
```

(See https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2194)